# ImportError: No module named oauth even after installing oauth2

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I am trying to access live twitter tweets.

I installed `oauth2` by running:

```
python setup.py install
```

The `cmd` showed this:

```
Installed c:\python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2-0.8-py2.7.egg
Finished processing dependencies for oauth2==1.5.211
```

But now when i try to use oauth2 module in my code like this:

```
import oauth2 as oauth
```

This error pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import oauth2
ImportError: No module named oauth2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you have multiple python installations on your Windows???

Comment: No. I just have Python-2.7.3 installed.

Comment: try `easy_install oauth2` , i do that and its oki , there is no problem

Comment: Look inside `c:\python27\lib\site-packages` (with `dir`, Explorer, whatever). Is there an egg file or directory named `oauth2`?

Comment: Also, that "Finished processing dependencies" should not be the last line of the install! If it is, nothing got installed, and that's your problem.